# Question about infrared receiver with metal shell to detect heart pulse rate?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, ir

I'm newbie to the world of arduino and environmental sensing. I have been searching for a while about how can I measure the heart pulse rate, I came through the following tutorial:

[Click Here](http://medicarduino.net/?page_id=204.)

I have the following [Arduino IR Receiver with metal shell module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KMMF7AO) that I want to use as the previous tutorial suggesting, but, the IR receiver used in the tutorial has no metal shell, so, my question is if they are both functioning the same way?
Can I position my IR Receiver exactly as the one in the tutorial or do I need some workaround to reach my goal based on the fact that it has a metal shell?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Proper" oxygen meters use a bimodal LED - red + IR - so there will be limitations to this. They also have a piece of copper foil wrapped around the sensor & heavily earthed, so your shielded sensor has, already, an advantage!

You should be able to use your receiver exactly the same way. If you can ground the shield, do so.